# how do i remove mesh from inside of the model?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

Basically the way i made the hand is i sculpted the palm withought the fingers and scultped the fingers independently and stuck em onto the hand, but to finish sculpting the hand i need to remove the mesh from inside the palm and remesh the part where the fingers connect to the palm, is there any way to do that? preferably withought altering the rest of the model.[image]
[image]

Comment: You can remesh but the size of the faces need to thin enough to preserve the shape

Comment: remeshing it completley is a problem because the remesh needs to be really small for the fingers to not get merged together and when i got too small blender starts lag really hard

Comment: Maybe try going into Edit mode and then, in face mode, Select->By Trait->Interior Faces, then delete them.
But that geometry looks very messy so I'm not sure it's work. 
You should probably just remesh it. If you don't want to affect the whole model then just cut the hand into a separate object before doing it and join them properly with a boolean afterwards